# Dropdown not work in responsive jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using responsive jquery datatable.

Check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/82v4p7cL/1/

```
<div id="tblSkippedItems_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><table id="tblSkippedItems" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblSkippedItems_info" style="width: 100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblSkippedItems" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 159px;" aria-label="Itemnumber: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Itemnumber</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblSkippedItems" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px; display: none;" aria-label="Location : activate to sort column ascending"></th></tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" style="">02-273-BU</td>
      <td style="display: none;"> 
         <select id="ddlTest" style="width: 300px">
      </td>
        </tr>
   <tr class="child">
      <td class="child" colspan="2">
         <ul data-dtr-index="1">
            <li data-dtr-index="2" data-dt-row="1" data-dt-column="2"><span class="dtr-title">Location <small>(Picking)</small></span> <span class="dtr-data"><span class="ClsLocName">N/A </span>  <select id="ddlTest" style="width: 300px"></select></span></li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table></div></div>
</div>
```

I have dropdown column in jquery datatable.

In responsive mode, new tr is created with class "child".
And old tr is hide.

Both tr contain dropdown with same id.
When I try to add options to dropdown using jquery, no effect on dropdown.

```
 var ddl = $('#DdlTest');
ddl.append($("<option></option>").val('0').html('Selectvalue'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Try using a different id in your dropdown, you can only have 1 element with a specific id in every page, the script is working but it will append the options on the first element with that specific id.

Comment: Your didn't provide any event when you click the _Add option_ button. Try to add a jquery click event then call `AddOption()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your html and jquery select. first you didn't close the `select` tag try closing it and second `ddlTest` is not equal to `DdlTest`. you need to fix these issues then append your option.

```
 <select id="ddlTest" style="width: 300px"></select>
```

JavaScript

```
var ddl = $('#ddlTest');
ddl.append($("<option value="0"></option>");
```